# Woocommerce: How to display input-radio for the Only One payment method on checkout page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

Payment Method: **BACS**
**The only one Payment Method disposable in the checkout page is BACS.**

The normal behavior of the **checkout page** is **NOT** display the input-radio like this.

```
<input id="payment_method_bacs" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="bacs" checked="checked" data-order_button_text="" style="display: none;">
```

I need to display the input-radio. Is it possible?

```
<input id="payment_method_bacs" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="bacs" checked="checked" data-order_button_text="" style="display: yes;">
```

Is there a Hook for that, or how can i modify this behavior please?
**Gratitude!**

Answer (score 1):

Well, this answer my question!
I inserted this element inside the file style.css in the child-theme and it works!

```
.payment_method_bacs .input-radio{
  display: block !important;
}
```